# Flask WTForms - Retrieve form data when submitting to a different route, i.e. a different POST route than the GET route which renders the form

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I would like to set up my URLs/endpoints according to REST as closely as possible, while still utilising Flask-WTForms.

I would like my form to render at `GET /posts/new`, and submit to `POST /post`.

With Flask-WTForms I can only work out how to get it to GET/POST to the same URL.

My current code looks like this:

```py
@post_bp.route('/posts/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_post_form():
    create_post_form = CreatePostForm()

    if create_post_form.validate_on_submit():
        return 'success'

    return render_template('create_post_form.html', form=create_post_form)
```

However I would like to be able to make it look something more like this, but I just can't seem to work it out:

```py
@post_bp.route('/posts/new', methods=['GET'])
def show_post_form():
    create_post_form = CreatePostForm()

    return render_template('create_post_form.html', form=create_post_form)
```

- this route only shows the form
- the form submits a POST request to /post

```html
<form action="{{url_for('shipment.C_shipment')}}" method="POST" novalidate>
```

- the `POST /post` route handles the submitted form and if there are errors for example, then it redirects back to `GET /posts/new`:

```py
@post_bp.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def create_post():
    create_post_form = CreatePostForm()

    if create_post_form.validate_on_submit():
        return "success!"

    if len(create_post_form.errors) != 0:
        for error in create_shipment_form.errors:
            for msg in create_shipment_form.errors[error]:
                flash(msg)

    return redirect(url_for('shipment.show_create_shipment_form'))
```

- i guess creating a new `CreatePostForm()` object here doesn't really work..

Any suggestions?

Comment: `url_for('shipment.C_shipment')` - is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new `CreatePostForm` is correct as it parses the submitted form data for you. This allows you to call `validate_on_submit()` on the form object.

I don't think you're generating the correct URL for the form action in your HTML snippet. The argument to `url_for()` should be the desired endpoint (see [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for)) which should be `<post_bp>.create_post`. This would be similar to your call

```
return redirect(url_for('shipment.show_create_shipment_form'))
```

If this does not fix the issue, please provide both frontend and backend error messages you receive when trying to send the data to `/post`.